# wxpython hide all sizer elements

Tags: wxpython, hide, sizer

I have a script that utilizes multiple panels depending on which lines of code are being executed at that time.  My intention is to show and hide panels as needed and use Layout after each change to keep everything nice and neat.  This is working for me in general, but I ran into a snag.  At first when the number of panels was small I was hiding the necessary ones via the panel names or other sizer item names.  As the script has become more complex that has ceased to be practical, so it was my intention to always hide everything each time, so I did not have to worry about keeping track of what was being displayed at any given time and then just show the panel that was needed at that point in execution.  Looking at sizer documentation I thought it would be a simple matter of using:

```
self.MainSizer.ShowItems(False)
```

but that generated the following error:

File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\wx-2.8-msw-unicode\wx_core.py", line 13192, in ShowItems
    return *core*.Sizer_ShowItems(*args, **kwargs)
wx._core.PyAssertionError: C++ assertion "wxAssertFailure" failed at ....\src\common\sizer.cpp(436) in wxSizerItem::Show(): can't show uninitialized sizer item

Comment: I figured it out.  Had to add show= 

`self.MainSizer.ShowItems(show=False)`

Comment: Did toy try **self.MainSizer.Hide()** ?

Comment: @Mike, MainSizer.Hide() would hide the entire sizer while what I want to do is show the sizer but hide all of widgets I have added to it.

Comment: `self.MainSizer.Hide()` expects some arguments. so it's throwing error for me. `Sizer.Hide() 
 arguments did not match any overloaded call`